# Error deploying nodejs app to Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I am catching the following error when I try to manually run the app.js file directly from the Microsoft Azure Console. Why? The app.js works fine on my localhost.
[image]

This is my app.js file:

```
'use strict';

var app = require('connect')();
var http = require('http');
var swaggerTools = require('swagger-tools');
var jsyaml = require('js-yaml');
var fs = require('fs');
var serverPort = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
  swaggerUi: '/swagger.json',
  controllers: './controllers',
  useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
};

// The Swagger document (require it, build it programmatically, fetch it from a URL, ...)
var spec = fs.readFileSync('./api/swagger.yaml', 'utf8');
var swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  // Validate Swagger requests
  app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

  // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));

  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

  // Start the server
  http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
  });
});
```

(The javascript code comes from swagger.io)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to start the node.js application running on Azure Web Apps via executing the command `node app.js` manually on Azure. As you have already an entrance file `app.js` or `server.js` and an IIS `web.config` in the root directory of your application, you can directly browse your nodejs application via the URL.

I tested the example project at https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/tree/master/examples/2.0 which should be similar with yours. It works fine on my side.

Please try to browse your application directly on browser.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.